# My application crashes when i touch the screen - OnTouch method fails

Tags: android, crash, touch

I have created an application where i have a camera preview. I am trying to create a touch event such that when i touch the preview, something will happen (let say, a toast will appear).
The problem is that when i am touching the preview, after 2 seconds the application crashes.
I have two classes:

CameraActivity:

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "CameraDemo";
    Preview preview;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);

         preview = new Preview(this);
        ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(preview);
        ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).setOnTouchListener(preview);

        Log.d(TAG, "Camera Activity Created.");
    }
}
```

and Preview:

```
class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnTouchListener {
private static final String TAG = "Preview";

SurfaceHolder mHolder;
public Camera camera;

Preview(Context context) {
    super(context);

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

// Called once the holder is ready
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera = Camera.open();
    try {
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

        camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
            // Called for each frame previewed
            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPreviewFrame called at: " +  System.currentTimeMillis());
                Preview.this.invalidate();
            }
        });

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }


}



// Called when the holder is destroyed
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
}

// Called when holder has changed
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    camera.startPreview();
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Toast.makeText(findViewById(R.id.preview).getContext(), "BEFORE SHUTTER", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return false;
}
 }
```

Can someone please help and tell me what i am doing wrong?

Here is the LogCat (the part where the crash appears):

```
03-08 12:11:48.335: D/AndroidRuntime(1167): Shutting down VM
03-08 12:11:48.335: W/dalvikvm(1167): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught    exception (group=0x40015578)
03-08 12:11:48.343: E/AndroidRuntime(1167): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 12:11:48.343: E/AndroidRuntime(1167): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-08 12:11:48.343: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at com.marakana.Preview.onTouch(Preview.java:80)
03-08 12:11:48.343: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at     android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3934)
03-08 12:11:48.343: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
03-08 12:11:48.343: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
03-08 12:11:48.343: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
03-08 12:11:48.343: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
03-08 12:11:48.343: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
03-08 12:11:48.343: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1733)
03-08 12:11:48.343: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1151)
03-08 12:11:48.343: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
03-08 12:11:48.343: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1717)
03-08 12:11:48.343: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2215)
03-08 12:11:48.343: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1886)
03-08 12:11:48.343: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-08 12:11:48.343: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-08 12:11:48.343: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-08 12:11:48.343: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 12:11:48.343: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-08 12:11:48.343: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
03-08 12:11:48.343: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-08 12:11:48.343: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 12:11:48.378: D/dalvikvm(1167): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 943K, 59% free 2633K/6407K, external 1596K/2108K, paused 15ms
03-08 12:11:48.531: D/dalvikvm(1167): GC_CONCURRENT freed 21K, 52% free 3084K/6407K, external 1596K/2108K, paused 2ms+26ms
03-08 12:11:56.109: I/Process(1167): Sending signal. PID: 1167 SIG: 9
```

Thanks

Comment: please send the logcat details

Comment: A first thing you should do to find the bug in your code is to take a look at the logcat.

Comment: Thaks for responding! i have attached the LogCat to the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an issue with context

```
Toast.makeText(findViewById(R.id.preview).getContext(), "BEFORE SHUTTER", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You cannot get context this way. In your constructor you pass in context:

```
Preview(Context context) {
```

I would create a private instance of context

```
private Context ctx;
```

and then in the constructor add

```
this.ctx = context;
```

and then change the toast message to

```
Toast.makeText(ctx, "BEFORE SHUTTER", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This will also give you context in most other places in your class too therefore making life a little easier.

Comment: awesome! Can you tick this as correct for other users to know this was the chosen solution.